# Read From Text File Without String in C Language

Tags: c, string, file

There is a restaurant menu in a text file as follows:

Product       Price (TL)

Pizza         75.99

Hamburger     21.50

Steak         40.00

Pasta         55.60

I need to read this menu from the text file, and print the menu without prices to terminal like below, !!!! without using string !!!!!;

Menu List :

1. Pizza
2. Hamburger
3. Steak
4. Pasta

I don't know how to do this

Comment: Start with something simple based on, say `int c; while((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF) { if(isalpha(c) || isspace(c)) fputc(c, stdout); }` then think about ignoring the heading, and adding line numbers when you have that working.

Comment: Handling string data without using strings sounds like a stupid assignment. Is it maybe only without using functions from `string.h`. While you can extract and print the required data from the csv file, this will be absolutely useless for any other activity in the program.

Comment: Or, stated another way, reading text data from a file without using strings sounds like a *trivial* assignment, because C has no string type!  As long as you don't use a double-quoted string literal anywhere in your code, I believe you'll have met the letter of the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Step1:
Function: `FILE *fopen(const char *filename, const char *mode)` can be used to open the file.
Step2:
Use function: `int fgetc(FILE *stream)` to read until you encounter a space. and store that then ignore the rest until u find a line feed. and keep doing this until you reach EOF
Step3:
Use function: `int printf ( const char * format, ... );` to print the result in a loop.
Step4:
Now, finally use `int fclose(FILE *stream)` to close the file.
And you are done. Good luck!
Please update your question with attempted code so that we can help you further

Comment: Please note the type returned by `int fgetc(FILE *stream)` is not `char*`.

Comment: Sorry my bad for some reason I had fgets() in my head when I wrote that.